# User does not have delivery config set to turn on SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I tried to enable MFA OTOP for the Cognito user pool user adminSetUserMFAPreference method but it is throwing the below error,
I have configured MFA as optional

```
User does not have delivery config set to turn on SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA
```

```
          let input = {
            Username: response.User.Username,
            UserPoolId: environment.awsUserPoolConfig.userPoolId,
            SoftwareTokenMfaSettings: {
              Enabled: true,
              PreferredMfa: true,
            },
          };
          await COGNITO_CLIENT.adminSetUserMFAPreference(
            input
          ).promise();
```

Comment: Same issue. I have 2 user pool, for one user pool this works perfectly, for other user pool I get the error. Strange!

Comment: @sureshrathnaraj please add the solution if you have figured it out. I skipped MFA because of this issue

Comment: Any update? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score -1):

This error means that you have not setup MFA for user. Enabling MFA is only possible once you setup MFA.

Setting up can be done using AssociateSoftwareTokenCommand and VerifySoftwareTokenCommand

In cognito, we cannot enforce user to setup MFA on the first login, if required this has to be handled separately outside of Cognito.

Hope this helps.